# Joomla server virus or any other

Tags: php, joomla, cron, server, virus

I have a simple Joomla site, sometimes it dies. I found a file containing the following code:

```
if(date('s',time())%2==0) die();
```

I deleted the code, and then it appeared in another file.

When I download the site via Akeeba and install it on localhost, and then delete all the bad code then the site is clean (and the virus doesn't return). But in my server the virus is still active.

Any idea how to fix the problem?

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a vulnerability in the website that a script or hacker is exploiting to reinfect the website.

Make sure you have updated to the latest version of Joomla in the series. For example this is currently Joomla 3.3.6 for the Joomla 3.x series.

More likely the issue is with a third party extension. Make a list of third party extensions via Extension Manager (the third party extensions are the ones that have something other than "Joomla Project" as the author). Remember that not all extensions use the Joomla updater so some updates have to be done manually. Run through the list and check that you are using all the latest versions. You can find the latest versions via http://extensions.joomla.org and/or the developer websites.

You should also check http://vel.joomla.org/ to ensure that you are not using any vulnerable extensions.

You should also reset administrator password(s), the database password and your hosting password.

Repeat the above steps for any other websites that share the same web hosting account.

Check that any CRON jobs in your hosting account are legitimate.

If you are serious about eradicating malware from your website, you should probably subscribe to myJoomla.com or have the website professionally scanned by Sucuri or some other security expert.

Alternatively, you may be able to eradicate the malware by deleting the website and restoring from a backup or deleting the website and rebuilding it from scratch taking care not to reintroduce the malware from backed up files.

Comment: Also see http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/2339/120 and similar answers over on http://joomla.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks you very much. I used joomla 3.3.6. I will contact my host to scan virus